# How to get a label next in Columns in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I would like to get a label next to these inputs in the columns. I would like the label on the left of the input. I have tried a few different ways to add a label but I haven't been able with no luck. Maybe you can help me with mapping these inputs so it doesnt give me the "`#<AdminUser:0x007ff1f5661090>`"

relevant code

```
panel "Order Details" do
  attributes_table_for resource do
    columns do
        column do
            span image_tag order.proof_url(:thumb).to_s
        end
        column do
            columns do
                column do
                    span order.id
                end
                column do
                    span order.start_date
                end
            end
            columns do
                column do
                    span order.admin_user 
                end
                column do
                    span order.end_date
                end
            end
            columns do
                column do
                    span order.customer
                end
                column do
                    span order.order_status
                end
            end
            columns do
                column do
                    span order.order_category
                end
                column do
                    span order.order_priority
                end
            end
            columns do
                column do
                    span order.order_type
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

[image: I even provided you an image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are printing the objects, so you get this `#<...>` stuff. What you want to do, and maybe is not that clear, is that you want to print the `AdminUser` name, the `Customer` name, the `OrderType` description, etc.
So you need to modify your code to something like this:

```
span order.admin_user.name

span order.customer.name

span order.order_category.description # Or whatever you do to describe the order type
```

You need to print the model attribute, instead of the model itself.